# How to redraw only single widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

No render all widgets. only render one widget.

Means not called build method because it's render all widgets.

Thanks for giving me your important time.

Comment: You are simply calling `set state` too high. Usually it's not a problem, but if it becomes a problem, refactor your code and make smaller widgets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This case we are use any state management like getx, provider and many more link in description.

GetX or Get:-
https://pub.dev/packages/get

Provider:- https://pub.dev/packages/provider

**OR**

We are use Builder widget.

Link:- https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Builder-class.html

Answer (score 2):

You can't update a widget UI without re-building. To avoid building every widget in a widget tree split your whole widget into small widgets. This will help re-building widgets separately. Also, use `const` constructors.

Answer (score 0):

you can use value notifier and wrap with valuelistnablebuilder to update only that widget when value changes of value notifier